# problem on homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

i am facing problem in showing that:

show that the maximum number of closed curves along which the surface 
may be cut without dividing it into two or more disjoint parts is 
 a topological invariant.

i am not able to understand which property of homeomorphism is not satisfied in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f\colon X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism and there exist $n$ closed curves $\gamma_i\colon S^1\to X$ such that $X\setminus\bigcup \gamma_i[S^1]$ is not connected, then we are to show that there are also $n$ curves in $Y$ with this property. Trying the curves $f\circ \gamma_i$ suggests itself.